# C# being sometimes 'plus' but sometimes 'add'?

Tags: c#

I don't get it why when I do:

```
int myInt = 2 + 2;
```

Then `myInt` will make `4`.

But when I does do the same but I put a word in...

```
int myInt = "2" + 2;
```

Then I get 22.

Does C# do math or strings?

Comment: That’s operator overloading, maybe, but I wasn’t aware you could do that in C# without casting…

Comment: is this at all possible?

Comment: `int myInt = "2" + 2;` doesn't compile.

Comment: Looks like some error in sample - clearly `string myInt = "2" + 2;` should not be surprising (same as `var myInt = "2" + 2;`); but sample in the post does not compile and thus "typographical error" seem to be the reason...

Comment: or `var myInt = 2 +2;` and `var myInt = "2" + 2;` would compile in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

This won't compile:

```
int myInt = "2" + 2;
```

But this will:

```
string myInt = "2" + 2;
```

Why? Because the `+` operator performs both addition for numeric types and string concatenation for strings. The ability to allow operators to perform different functions in different types is known as [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) and is a key feature of C#. In fact, [you can overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx) these and many other operators in your own custom types.

Because one operator is a string, the compiler recognizes that this should be treated as string concatenation, and so it passes both parameters to the [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, where any non-strings are converted to strings by calling the [`Object.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can override the behavior of operators such as +

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx

```
class Plus
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(+5);        // unary plus
        Console.WriteLine(5 + 5);     // addition
        Console.WriteLine(5 + .5);    // addition
        Console.WriteLine("5" + "5"); // string concatenation
        Console.WriteLine(5.0 + "5"); // string concatenation 
        // note automatic conversion from double to string
    }
}
/*
Output:
5
10
5.5
55
55
*/
```

Comment: But that doesn't compile...

Comment: as i stated in my comment above, i presumed the OP meant 'var', then both would.